# Angular.js API calls - should I use a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, trello

I'm working on an Electron app, utilizing the Trello API, Node.js (and the Node-Trello package), and Angular.js ([github repo](https://github.com/Banjerr/electrello))

Upon user authorizing their Trello app, I save some profile data; some of which is a list of IDs of all their Trello boards.

I have a controller which handles displaying their list of boards. In this controller, I pull the list of board IDs form the DB and get an array like

```
["893482938480", "0938492830"]
```

and then I call a function to which I pass this array of board IDs, like so...

```js
// get data for boards
$scope.get_board_data = function(boardIDArray) {
  for(var i = 0; i < boardIDs.length; i++){
    t.get("/1/boards/" + boardIDs[i], function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      board_info = data;
      board_names.push(board_info['name']);
      $scope.board_names = board_names;
      //console.log($scope.board_names);
      return $scope.board_names
    });
  }
}

$scope.board_array = $scope.get_board_data(boardIDs);
```

the issue is that if I `console.log` $scope.board_names outside of the function, then I get `undefined`. BUT if I log inside the function, then I get the desired data. I'm a little stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

p.s. i've also tried using `$watch` on $scope.board_names, but i'm still getting `undefined`. this is what i tried...

```js
$scope.$watch('$scope.board_names', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('$scope.board_array: ' + newValue);
});
```

**EDIT** well, it appears that this code does work; i changed `$scope.board_array = $scope.get_board_data(boardIDs);` to just `$scope.get_board_data(boardIDs);` and then when I click on a menu item, the view finally realizes there is data for it to use.

**New Question** how can I make the view get this data on page load?

Should this be a factory? is that what they are used for?

Comment: Is that function in the same location you are trying to call console.log? like is it in the controller?

Comment: What is the t.get variable? is that the Angular $Http package?

Comment: all of the above code inside the same controller. the ```t.get``` is the Trello object set up by the node-trello package

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of using a plain factory, you instead use a [Resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).  They are specially created factories made specifically to handle REST calls.  Check out [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) below for more information.

Not only are resources made specifically for this, but they also allow for you to create a centralized system that allows you to easily add more REST calls as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Factory:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
  angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('YourFactoryName', ['$http', function ($http) {
      //Add your other things you need to inject I don't know what your using. 
      //Probably pass your t object, or if you can inject it here, if it is in fact a service of its own
      var factory = {};
      factory.get_board_data  = function (boardIDArray) {
        for(var i = 0; i < boardIDs.length; i++){
          t.get("/1/boards/" + boardIDs[i], function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            board_info = data;
            board_names.push(board_info['name']);

            return board_names;
        });
      };
  };
  return factory;
  }]);
}())
```

Call it with `$scope.board_array=YourFactoryName.get_board_data();`

You can call this at the beginning of your controller if you want it to be loaded right away.